# How to calculate working time in Google Sheet

Tags: time, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a task to calculate the working hours in Google Sheet.

Below is my sheet screenshot, where I am facing an issue if the logout time is in AM.

**Example:**

[image]

**Current Formula:**

`=(hour(D6-C6-E6)*60 + minute(D6-C6-E6))/60`

Answer (score 0):

```
=IFERROR((HOUR(D6-C6-E6)*60 + MINUTE(D6-C6-E6))/60,
 ((HOUR(D6+5000-C6-E6)*60 + MINUTE(D6+5000-C6-E6))/60)+12)
```

[image: 5]

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
 =24*(D6-C6-E6+(D6<C6))
```

Perhaps formatted as Number to two decimal places.